# How to get the size of all files in a S3 bucket without versioning?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My bucket size is over 150 TB now and the number of files is over 100k. I am working on a better versioning policy now but I need to know the current size without versions, so I can balance the price and effort with my solution vs moving them to Glacier. I have folders as well as files in it.

Afaik, AWS only exposes the API for getting the total size of a bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
aws s3 ls s3://<bucketname> --recursive  | grep -v -E "(Bucket: |Prefix: |LastWriteTime|^$|--)" | awk 'BEGIN {total=0}{total+=$3}END{print total/1024/1024" MB"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also take advantage of [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) to obtain a detailed listing of the bucket.

Alternatively, you could use [Amazon S3 Intelligent-Tiering — a New Amazon S3 Storage Class](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/11/s3-intelligent-tiering/) to do it all for you!